# Java ReentrantLock.unlock/await()/signal() not throwing IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Where am I going wrong? Even though my consumer Thread is not holding the lock, the program is not throwing IllegalMonitorStateException for any of the lock calls (unlock/await/signal).

**Update:**

```
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private final Condition producers = lock.newCondition();
private final Condition consumers = lock.newCondition();

@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {
        try {
            //lock.lockInterruptibly();
            try {
                while (sharedResource.isEmpty()) {
                    printErr(name + " : Queue Empty ..");
                    consumers.await(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                }

                String obj = sharedResource.remove(0);
                printOut(name + " : " + obj);
                if (obj.equals(POISON_PILL)) {
                    sharedResource.add(POISON_PILL);
                    // System.err.println(name +" Taking break");
                    break;
                }

                producers.signal();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // if(debug)System.err.println("Consumer Looping");
    }
}
```

void java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock()

As per Java [Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#unlock%28%29). 
public void unlock()
Attempts to release this lock.
If the current thread is the holder of this lock then the hold count is decremented. If the hold count is now zero then the lock is released. `If the current thread is not the holder of this lock then IllegalMonitorStateException is thrown`.

Comment: This looks like Java code.  Why did you tag it with c# as well?

Comment: Why would they throw exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Question appears to be based on some incorrect assumptions / statements.

1. The Java `ReentrantLock` class does not have an `await` or `signal` method.
2. That means that `consumers` is (most likely) not a `ReentrantLock` ... and nothing in your code snippet calls `signal` (or `singnal` (sic)).
3. According to the javadoc, the `ReentrantLock` lock and unlock methods do not throw `IllegalMonitorStateException`.  And I wouldn't expect them to, because the lock and unlock methods are not operating as primitive monitors / mutexes.

AFAIK, the only way to get that exception out of a `Lock` object would be to use the primitive mutex operations `wait` and `notify` ... which seems a perverse use of the `Lock` object.  (If you want to use those operations, *any* object will suffice, including a plain `Object` instance.)

The `Lock` classes are designed to provide locking that is orthogonal to Java primitive locks, and not constrained to be strictly block-structured.  They do not provide directly provide await and signal.  If you want that, you need to create a `Condition`; e.g. using `Lock.newCondition()`.  Note that the Condition.await and signal methods *typically* will throw `IllegalMonitorStateException` if the current thread doesn't hold the `Lock` ... but that behaviour is implementation specific; see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html).

---

So assuming that `consumers` is a `Condition`, then there are a couple of reasons why it might not be throwing the exception:

1. It might not be a condition for the `Lock` that is denoted by `lock`.
2. The actual `Lock` class may provide `Condition` objects that don't require the lock to be held ...

Unfortunately, your code snippet is missing some vital clues that would address those points.

---

**UPDATE**

I converted your code into something that I could run:

```
package test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Lochy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        Condition producers = lock.newCondition();
        Condition consumers = lock.newCondition();

        while (true) {
            try {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        System.out.println("wait " + i);
                        consumers.await(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    }
                    producers.signal();
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run that, I see a `IllegalMonitorStateException` at the `unlock`.

When I comment out the `unlock()` I see `IllegalMonitorStateException` at the `await`.

In hindsight, it is clear what it happening.  The `IllegalMonitorStateException` is thrown by `await` in both cases, but when you call `unlock()` in the `finally` block, that throws ANOTHER `IllegalMonitorStateException` ... so you don't see the first one.

In short, the methods are behaving exactly as the spec says they should.

Comment: Updated my posting. consumers & producers are conditions. As per the java doc if the current thread is not holding the lock, the call to unlock with throw IllegalMonitorStateException.